# Hiding parent container if children are not :visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm pulling my hair out on this one...

I'm using a jquery live search filter.  Which works great.  And allows me this code to attach and modify events.

```
// live search for items
$('input#live_search').quicksearch('li.menu-item', {
      'delay': 300,
      'loader': 'span.loading',
      'bind': 'keyup click',
      'show': function () {
        $(this).show();
      },
      'hide': function () {
        $(this).hide();
      },
      'prepareQuery': function (val) {
        return new RegExp(val, "i");
      },
      'testQuery': function (query, txt, _row) {
        return query.test(txt);
      }
});
```

The list items being filtered are each part of their own unordered list and own section.  What I want to say is on keyup.  If all of the list items in that particular unordered list are hidden.  Hide that entire parent container...

Ive gotten close in so many ways.  But there always seems to be a snag.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

The HTML renders like this:

```
<section id="calzone" class="menu-category">
<header class="category-header cf">text in here</header>
<ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item even" style="display: list-item; ">
        text in here
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item odd" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item even" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
     </li>

    <li class="menu-item odd" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
     </li>
</ul>
</section>
<section id="appetizer" class="menu-category">
<header class="category-header cf">text in here</header>
<ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item even" style="display: none;">
        text in here
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item odd" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item even" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
     </li>

    <li class="menu-item odd" style="display: none; ">
        text in here
     </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML. Seems like  `$(this).parent().hide();` should do the work :)

Comment: Just added the html.  Thanks Marco...  What I'm trying to do is hide the entire section.menu-category if none of the ul.menu-items are visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('section').each( function() {
  var hiddenLI = $(this).children('ul').children('li').is(':visible');

    if(!(hiddenLI)) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Searches the LI's to see if they are visible, if not hide's section.
(Will not hide if some are visible and some are not.)

But when you got mixed hidden/shown elements, you might not get a consistent result :)

Comment: Marco!! This worked great.  I just needed to bind it to the keyup event in my input.  And it works!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!$("parent").children().is(':visible')) {
  $("parent").hide();
}
```

Should about do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but this needs to be binded to the keyup event 'input#live_search'.